# Is there a built in function for length of boost::numeric::interval

Tags: c++, boost, interval-arithmetic

I'm typing the following in my code

```
boost::numeric::interval<double> foo = ...;
double length = std::abs(foo.upper() - foo.lower());
```

It surprises me I can't find a simple utility in [boost::numeric::interval](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/interval.htm) that calculates the length. I'd expect a length function so that I can do

```
boost::numeric::interval<double> foo = ...;
double length = length(foo);
```

Is this either

- missing from the library as an oversight
- missing from the library for good reason as it doesn't fit the concept
- there but under another name which I've failed to see

Obviously I can write a simple inline function to do this but I'm a bit surprised that I have to given that I see functions like min and max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found it after I posted the question

Answer is "width"

```
boost::numeric::interval<double> foo = ...;
double length = width(foo);
```

Comment: @user1810087 - What's the issue with that exactly?